# Node.js & Express & S3 / some requests are stuck

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm using node.js and s3, with this [module](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).

Here is the relvant code:

```
if (data.Contents[0].Size > 42500000) {
    var s3newclient = new AWS.S3({
        "accessKeyId": "acc-value",
        "secretAccessKey": "sec-value",
        "region": "us-east-1"
    });
    var s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: url.substring(1, url.length)
    }
    var download = s3newclient.getObject(s3Params);
    response.setHeader("content-type", 'application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="' + fileName + '"' + "; filename*=UTF-8''" + fileName + "");
    var downloadStream = download.createReadStream();
    downloadStream.pipe(response);
    downloadStream.on('error', function(err) {
        logger.info(err)
        logger.info("(readFileInStorage): Error! in  url: " + url);
        response.end();
    })
    downloadStream.on('end', function() {
        response.end();
    })
```

I get the request, and some files are sent correctly for the client, but for some reason after 5-6 files, the module is stopped for responding. No error is raised in `downloadstream`, but the client doesn't get any respond from my application.

Any ideas?